# Django Application with AWS ElastiCache, 500 Errors

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache, pylibmc

I setup Django Cache with Memcached (with pylibmc backend).

My settings look like this:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.PyLibMCCache',
        'LOCATION': 'LOCATION:PORT',
    }
}
```

I am only caching a view using the cache_page() decorator.

From my end, everything seems to be working fine for this cached view. However, when I use [Google PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) on the URL, every other run returns a 500 error.

My error logs don't seem to show any information. Just that 500 errors were returned for the Google PageSpeed Bot.

The website is not under heavy-load, so i don't think there is any cache stampede or similar issue involved.

Any help here, thank you.

EDIT: I noticed that when I set DEBUG=True. This problem seems to go away... but of course I cannot leave DEBUG=True.

Comment: Do you have a load balancer in front of the Django server? How about a reverse proxy like Nginx?

Comment: Yes I have a load balancer. No reverse proxy that I'm aware of. Launched the application with elastic beanstalk.

Comment: Elastic beanstalk uses a reverse proxy. You need to be checking all the logs. Also, do you have more than one server behind the load balancer?

Comment: No, I only have 1 server. Which log files should I look into, the error log files don't seem to show anything.